# How to view current history in Skype chat window with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, skype

When editing a conversation in conversation window, you normally have to refer back to what the other talker just mentioned.

You can do it by rolling up a bit by mouse, but you have click first in the pane above the edit box and scroll with mouse.

Is there any keyboard shortcut for this if I need to move back and forth and send messages?

Comment: Isn't it possible to Tab or Shift+Tab to that pane, and then use the arrow or PgUp/PgDn keys?

Comment: @Kar it's possible, to tab, but it tabs more than once each time, do you mean backward tab or what?becoz if you just tab, it won't go there.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, that's why I was asking you to Tab or Shift+ Tab and see.